# maven exec plugin doesn't recognize cucumber test class

Tags: maven, cucumber

I am trying to start cucumber tests from maven exec . But for some reason main test runner is not recognized as cucumber test class.

java.lang.Exception: The specified mainClass doesn't contain a main method with appropriate signature.

my pom entry below . Does anyone had this ussue before ?please provide some pointers  to move forward.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Gherkins -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${project.cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${project.cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${project.cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>


<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>scenario-tests</id>
              <phase>test</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>               
          <configuration>
            <mainClass>com.mytest.RunScenarioTest</mainClass>
            <arguments>                             
            <argument>--glue</argument><argument>com.mytest.steps</argument>
            <argument>features</argument>   <argument>src/main/resources/features</argument>
            <argument>path</argument>   <argument>src/main/resources/features</argument>
            <arg value="--format"/>  <arg value="html:bin/cucumber-html-report"/>
            </arguments>
          </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Why not using the default via surefire instead of trying to run via exec-maven-plugin...as the [docs say](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm)...

Comment: sunfire is not recognizing cucumber tests . So plugin org.codehaus.mojo  is used

Comment: khmarbaise is right. The usual practice is to use the surefire plugin, often with JUnit, to run cucumber. Surefire has defaults for its paths so it is import to follow the default folder structure.  For a working example (and out of the goodness of my heart) you can review [this](http://github.com/mikejramsey56/cuc_jav_webdriver)..This example works best if used with Eclipse.

Comment: you are correct . Thanks guys . default surefire should do the trick